# Can only download one file

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am running into a issue when I attempt to download a second file after the first file has completed.

This is the error:

> System.IO.IOException: 'Cannot create "C:\Users\user\Desktop\d.zip" because a file or directory with the same name already exists.'

This file does not exist so have no idea what is happening.

Code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim req As System.Net.WebRequest
    Dim resp As System.Net.WebResponse
    req = Net.WebRequest.Create("https://filedownloads.000webhostapp.com/RedAlert1_Online.rar")
    resp = req.GetResponse
    req.Method = Net.WebRequestMethods.Http.Get
    download_size = resp.ContentLength
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = download_size

    File_name = InputBox("Please Enter File Name!")
    File_save = File_save + "\" + File_name + ".zip"

    If File_name.Length > 0 Then
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("https://filedownloads.000webhostapp.com/RedAlert1_Online.rar", (File_save), "", "", False, 360000, True)
        Timer1.Start()
        Button1.Hide()
    End If
End Sub

Dim download_size As Long
Dim downloaded_size As Long

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    downloaded_size = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(File_save).Length
    ProgressBar1.Value = downloaded_size
End Sub
```

I do have another block of code the same as this for the second download within the block I just changed which progress bars, timers etc will start.

Comment: After generating your File_save value, it might be worthwhile adding a check to see if the file already exists. Then you could prompt user to see if they want to overwrite or not.

Comment: To check if the file exist? @DeanOC

Comment: What do you not understand about the information you found when you Googled "vb.net check if file exists"? You did do that web search, didn't you? You wouldn't expect us to waste our time explaining to you what you can easily find for yourself with a tiny bit of effort, would you? We're here to help with the hard stuff, not do the easy stuff so you don't have to try.

Comment: Before you start to download the file, you have to make sure the file does not exist. If it exist as per the need, either rename the existing file or delete that file or inform user that new file name is required.

Comment: @MukulVarshney The file does not exist already!

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have googled searched this but is not helping, the only things that come up are about the file already existing, However the file does not already exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below to check if file already exist before downloading. I cannot show the code in comments, hence writing it as answer. By the way, url has `.rar` extension while File_save has `.zip` extension.

```
If File_name.Length > 0 Then
    If File.Exists(File_save) Then
        MessageBox.Show("File already exist")
    Else
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("https://filedownloads.000webhostapp.com/RedAlert1_Online.rar", (File_save), "", "", False, 360000, True)
        Timer1.Start()
        Button1.Hide()
    End If
End If
```